# I am trying to make a responsive nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, responsive

I have the idea of having the anchor tags show up when they're set to active and I have tried using JavaScript to access them and make them active when clicking on a div/button (I tried with button but it didn't work out.).

The problem is that nothing happens. I ran through my code and didn't find where I can be wrong.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Начало</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d2896764d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="ResponsiveMenu.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="nav">
    <button class="dot_a">
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: transparent; width: 5px; height: 5px;"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ff4757;"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ffa502"></span>
      <span class="dot" style="background-color: #2ed573;"></span>
  </button>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><a class="anchors" href="Index.html"><i class="fas fa-house-damage"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;НАЧАЛО</a></li>
      <li><a class="anchors" href="HtmlPage.html"><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;HTML&CSS</a></li>
      <li><a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ИНСТРУМЕНТИ</a></li>
      <li><a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗАДАЧИ</a></li>
      <li><a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗА НАС</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

IndexStyle.css:

```
body {
  background-image: url(1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.pro_column1 {
  width: 15%;
}

.pro_column2 {
  width: 85%;
}

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  /*opacity: 60%;*/
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
  /*background:#3c6382;
  /*box-shadow:0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
  /*border: solid black 2px;*/
}

.nav-list {
  display:none;
}

.nav-list.active {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  color: #747d8c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.dot_a {
  /*float: right;*/
  color: #747d8c;
  /*display: block;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*position: fixed; /* or absolute */
}

i {
  /*float: right;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #747d8c;
  padding: 32px 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .nav a {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  div.dot_a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .dot {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .nav a:active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```
ResponsiveMenu.js:
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.dot_a');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-list');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Comment: have you try to debug your js code?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: [https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/)

Comment: Is there any other way to debug your code?

Comment: you need to move <script src="ResponsiveMenu.js" ></script> to just before the end of the body tag.  I added the full HTML in the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take this one step at a time, first lets look at the HTML. The center tag is no longer supported in HTML5 so I removed it. Second you had an extra quotation mark in your last anchor which I removed. In order to get all the links to show at once you should wrap them in a container. In this case a list makes the most sense. I have created a nav-list for you and wrapped all your anchor tags in an li tag.

As far as your CSS I noticed you were using `.anchor:active` which is a Pseudo class. This is not the same as having a class of anchor AND a class of active. If you want to select a class of anchor that also has a class of active you would use `.anchor.active`. In this case the active class is going on the nav-list so I style it using `.nav-list.active`

Now for the Javascript. Instead of using it to loop over all the anchor tags and setting them to active individually you can now just toggle the active class on your nav-list. This will make all the links appear at the same time.

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.dot_a');
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-list');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.pro_column1 {
  width: 15%;
}

.pro_column2 {
  width: 85%;
}

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  /*opacity: 60%;*/
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
  /*background:#3c6382;
  /*box-shadow:0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
  /*border: solid black 2px;*/
}

.nav-list {
  display:none;
}

.nav-list.active {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  color: #747d8c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.dot_a {
  /*float: right;*/
  color: #747d8c;
  /*display: block;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*position: fixed; /* or absolute */
}

i {
  /*float: right;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #747d8c;
  padding: 32px 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .nav a {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  div.dot_a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .dot {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .nav a:active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <button class="dot_a">
    <span class="dot" style="background-color: transparent; width: 5px; height: 5px;"></span>
    <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ff4757;"></span>
    <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ffa502"></span>
    <span class="dot" style="background-color: #2ed573;"></span>
</button>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a class="anchors" href="Index.html"><i class="fas fa-house-damage"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;НАЧАЛО</a></li>
    <li><a class="anchors" href="HtmlPage.html"><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;HTML&CSS</a></li>
    <li><a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ИНСТРУМЕНТИ</a></li>
    <li><a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗАДАЧИ</a></li>
    <li><a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗА НАС</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you spent. I got a questions till tho. Does it work fo ya when you run it, beacause nothing happened here when i try pressing the buttons. When i run it as a code snippet in stakoverflow tho it works amazing.<3

Comment: Two things could be happening either you have not copied over the CSS I added or you still have style="pointer-events: none;" on whatever you are clicking on. Check those and get back to me.

Comment: I inspected the page and on the menu source it appears to throw an error. It says:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
And it underlines the addEventListener line.

Comment: And i checked, everything is as you showed, sir.

Comment: Ok, update your question with the code you have now and Ill take a look.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by update your question?

Comment: At the top of this page is your question which contains the code you started with. Scroll down a little bit and you will see  4 buttons. Share, edit, delete and flag. Click the edit button and replace the code you currently have posted on this question with the code you have now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241011/discussion-between-cartofcartofski-and-kjek-code).

Comment: Done! I am pretty sure i exactly copied what you sent me.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to make the nav items active on click here's some issues to fix

1- querySelector returns only the first element in the list, so here you have 5 elements with class of anchors so it'll return the first anchor tag with class of .anchors and therefore you need querySelectorAll

Read more about querySelector here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

And querySelectorAll in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Briefly querySelectorAll returns a nodeList that you can treat as an array so you need to loop over this array and set the onclick event on each element like so

```
const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".anchors");

navbarLinks.forEach((link) =>
    link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.target.classList.toggle("active");
    })
);
```

2- you don't appear to have a class called active so classList.toggle would not work add this to your css

```
.active {
    background-color: #ddd !important;
    color: black;
}
```

3- you have a small bug in your html, the last anchor tag (a href="#"") notice that it has 2 double quotes for closing

4- with the previous code in (2) you'll notice being able to select multiple values which is not what we want therefore you should remove active class from all other anchor tags when 1 is active and you can achieve this with the following code

```
link.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    link.classList.remove("active");
});
```

blur works when you're not focusing on the element anymore
check MDN here for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

here's a working example

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".dot_a");
const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".anchors");

navbarLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.classList.add("active");
  });

  link.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    link.classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

.pro_column1 {
  width: 15%;
}

.pro_column2 {
  width: 85%;
}

.nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  /*opacity: 60%;*/
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 850px;
  /*background:#3c6382;
  /*box-shadow:0px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
  /*border: solid black 2px;*/
}

.nav a {
  /*float: right;*/
  color: #747d8c;
  /*display: block;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*position: fixed; /* or absolute */
}

.anchors {
  /*float: right;*/
  color: #747d8c;
  /*display: block;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*position: fixed; /* or absolute */
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation: 1s ease-in forwards;
}
.active {
  background-color: #ddd !important;
  color: black !important;
}
.dot_a {
  /*float: right;*/
  color: #747d8c;
  /*display: block;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*position: fixed; /* or absolute */
}

i {
  /*float: right;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #747d8c;
  padding: 32px 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .nav a {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

  div.dot_a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .nav {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .dot {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .nav a:active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Начало</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.jpg">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="ResponsiveMenu.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d2896764d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="ResponsiveMenu.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="dot_a" style="pointer-events: none;">
        <span class="dot" style="background-color: transparent; width: 5px; height: 5px;"></span>
        <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ff4757;"></span>
        <span class="dot" style="background-color: #ffa502"></span>
        <span class="dot" style="background-color: #2ed573;"></span>
      </div>

      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-house-damage"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;НАЧАЛО</a>

      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;HTML&CSS</a>

      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ИНСТРУМЕНТИ</a>

      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗАДАЧИ</a>

      <a class="anchors" href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ЗА НАС</a>
    </nav>
  </center>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir that is very helpful. I have always wanted to learn more about js but it seems hard for me. Unfortunately, the thing i am looking for is creating a responsive nav bar. Therefor i will need to have an element that slides in and out a menu when clicked. I will use the useful suggestions of your code aswell tho. <3